# Custom format to JSON

Tags: python, json

**How can i convert** the following line(not sure what format is this) **to JSON format?**

```
[root=Root [key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=Key3 [key3_1=value3_1, key3_2=value3_2, key3_3=Key3_3 [key3_3_1=value3_3_1]], key4=value4]]
```

where `Root`, `Key3`, `Key3_3` denote complex elements.

to

```
{
        "root": {
                "key1" : "value1",
                "key2" : "value2",
                "key3" : {
                        "key3_1" : "value3_1",
                        "key3_2" : "value3_2",
                        "key3_3" : {
                                "key3_3_1" : "value3_3_1"
                        }
                },
                "key4" : "value4
        }
}
```

I am looking for approach and not solution. If you are down-voting this question, Please comment why you are doing so.

Comment: Are `root`, `key1`, `key3_1` etc, standard key names for that format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `x` be a string with the above serialization.

First, lets replace the occurrences of `Root`, `Key3` and `Key3_3` with empty strings

```
# the string fragments like "root=Root [" need to be replaced by "root=["
# to achieve this, we match the regex pattern "\w+ ["
# This matches ALL instances in the input string where we have a word bounded by "=" & " [",
# i.e. "Root [", "Key3 [", "Key3_3" are all matched. as will any other example you can think of 
# where the `word` is composed of letters numbers or underscore followed
# by a single space character and then "["
# We replace this fragment with "[", (which we will later replace with "{")
# giving us the transformation "root=Root [" => "root=["
import re
o = re.compile(r'\w+ [[]')
y = re.sub(o, '[', x, 0)
```

Then, lets split the resulting string into words and non words

```
# Here we split the string into two lists, one containing adjacent tokens (nonwords)
# and the other containing the words
# The idea is to split / recombine the source string with quotes around all our words

w = re.compile(r'\W+')
nw = re.compile(r'\w+')

words = w.split(y)[1:-1] # ignore the end elements which are empty.
nonwords = nw.split(y) # list elements are contiguous non-word characters, i.e not a-Z_0-9
struct = '"{}"'.join(nonwords) # format structure of final output with quotes around the word's placeholder.
almost_there = struct.format(*words) # insert words into the string
```

And finally, replace the square brackets with squigly ones, and `=` with `:`

```
jeeson = almost_there.replace(']', '}').replace('=', ':').replace('[', '{')
# "{'root':{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':{'key3_1':'value3_1', 'key3_2':'value3_2', 'key3_3':{'key3_3_1':'value3_3_1'}}, 'key4':'value4'}}"
```

Comment: It's not a simple regex problem. The data he wants to parse can be much more complex and also, won't contain any predefined key (names).

Comment: @ArunAllamsetty the task was convert a given line to json, there was no discription of a format. If program solves it - it maybe not complete solution for the poster, but at least doesn't deserve downvote. So +1 (I wanted to give the similar solution, before actually noticing this one)

Comment: @ArunAllamsetty, I don't understand why this is not a simple regex problem. Can you provide a valid input which would not be converted by the method I have above? From what I can see, the input is sequence of  words (`key1 value1` etc.) separated by tokens (`= , [ ]`), and there's a particular expression of a word bounded by (`= [`), which needs to be parsed out.

Comment: @ArunAllamsetty, also, i'm not sure where in my code you see a reliance of predefined key names

Comment: If we follow the exact steps you gave, then we won't be able to convert the second data string I have in my answer, because we won't be replacing `Key3_2`. And there is your reliance on predefined keys.

Comment: Oh boy, I don't think you tried running the snippet before commenting or downvoting. `o = re.compile(r'\w+ [[]')` & `y = re.sub(o, '[', x, 0)` will remove any word that comes before `[`. `Key3_2`, `foo` etc... all work. Here's a pythonfiddle of this code successfully parsing your example input (which you claim it can't). http://pythonfiddle.com/custom-format-to-json/. I'll edit my answer and add comments to aid comprehension. As a bonus, this code preserves the order of the keys in the input string, which your example code does not.

Comment: I agree I did not actually run the code. And now that I have, I admit my mistake. So I take back my downvote. The added explanation helped :) But just FYI, in case of JSON serialization, the order does not really matter. It will be deserialized to a `dict` anyway.

Comment: assuming the OP intended to deserialize it to dict, it would be problematic if he needs an ordered dict instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had to spend around two hours on this, but I think I have something which would work all the cases based on the format you provided. If not, I am sure it'll be a minor change. Even though you asked only for the idea, since I coded it up anyway, here's the Python code.

```
import json

def to_json(cust_str):
    from_index = 0
    left_indices = []
    levels = {}

    level = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(cust_str):
        if char == '[':
            level += 1
            left_indices.append(i)
            if level in levels:
                levels[level] += 1
            else:
                levels[level] = 1
        elif char == ']':
            level -= 1

    level = max(levels.keys())
    value_stack = []
    while True:
        left_index = left_indices.pop()
        right_index = cust_str.find(']', left_index) + 1
        values = {}
        pairs = cust_str[left_index:right_index][1:-1].split(',')

        if levels[level] > 0:
            for pair in pairs:
                pair = pair.split('=')
                values[pair[0].strip()] = pair[1]
        else:
            level -= 1
            for pair in pairs:
                pair = pair.split('=')
                if pair[1][-1] == ' ':
                    values[pair[0].strip()] = value_stack.pop()
                else:
                    values[pair[0].strip()] = pair[1]
        value_stack.append(values)
        levels[level] -= 1
        cust_str = cust_str[:left_index] + cust_str[right_index:]

        if levels[1] == 0:
            return json.dumps(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Data in custom format
    cust_str = '[root=Root [key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=Key3 [key3_1=value3_1, key3_2=value3_2, key3_3=Key3_3 [key3_3_1=value3_3_1]], key4=value4]]'
    # Data in JSON format
    json_str = to_json(cust_str)
    print json_str
```

The idea is that, we map the number of levels the `dict`s go to in the custom format and the number of values which are not strings corresponding to those levels. Along with that, we keep track of the indices of the `[` character in the given string. We then start from the innermost `dict` representation by popping the stack containing the `[` (left) indices and parse them. As each of them is parsed, we remove them from the string and continue. The rest you can probably read in the code.

I ran it for the data you gave and the result is as follows.

```
{
   "root":{
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":{
         "key3_2":"value3_2",
         "key3_3":{
            "key3_3_1":"value3_3_1"
         },
         "key3_1":"value3_1"
      },
      "key1":"value1",
      "key4":"value4"
   }    
}
```

Just to make sure it works for more general cases, I used this custom string.

```
[root=Root [key1=value1, key2=Key2 [key2_1=value2_1], key3=Key3 [key3_1=value3_1, key3_2=Key3_2 [key3_2_1=value3_2_1], key3_3=Key3_3 [key3_3_1=value3_3_1]], key4=value4]]
```

And parsed it.

```
{
   "root":{
      "key2":{
         "key2_1":"value2_1"
      },
      "key3":{
         "key3_2":{
            "key3_2_1":"value3_2_1"
         },
         "key3_3":{
            "key3_3_1":"value3_3_1"
         },
         "key3_1":"value3_1"
      },
      "key1":"value1",
      "key4":"value4"
   } 
}
```

Which, as far as I can see, is how it should be parsed. Also, remember, **do not** strip the values since the logic depends on the whitespace at the end of values which should have the `dict`s as values (if that makes any sense).